# Is there a way to split a i18n translation?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, split, i18next, react-i18next

OK, so I got this component that animating my titles. But know, I want to translate my application with i18n, but problem is, I was using `.split()` function to make an array of words of my titles, I know that `.split()` is taking only string, and all I tested return me a JSX Element. So I can't split my pages title.

Is there another way to do it, to keep my translation ?

Here is an exemple of my pages with the component title and what I tried *(I also tried with Translation from react-i18next, but same result)*

### About.tsx

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import AnimatedLetters from "../AnimatedLetters/AnimatedLetters"
import { Div } from "../Layout/Layout.elements";
import { useTranslation, Trans } from "react-i18next";


const About = () => {

    const [letterClass, setLetterClass] = useState<string>('text-animate');
    const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setLetterClass('text-animate-hover')
        }, 3000)
    }, [])

    const getTranslation = (value: string) => {

        return <Trans t={t}>{value}</Trans>;
    }

  return (
    <Div>
        <div className="container about-page">
            <div className="text-zone">
                <h1>
                    <AnimatedLetters
                        strArray={getTranslation('About.Title').split("")}
                        idx={15}
                        letterClass={letterClass}
                    />
                </h1>
                

        </div>
    </Div>
  )
}

export default About
```

Before decide to translate, I was making like that :

```js
<AnimatedLetters
    strArray={"About us".split("")}
    idx={15}
    letterClass={letterClass}
/>
```

### AnimatedLetters.tsx

```js
import { FunctionComponent } from "react"
import { Span } from "./AnimatedLetters.elements"

type Props = {
    letterClass: string,
    strArray: any[],
    idx: number
}

const AnimatedLetters: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ letterClass, strArray, idx }) => {

  return (
    <Span>
        {
            strArray.map((char: string, i: number) => (
                <span key={char + i} className={`${letterClass} _${i + idx}`} >
                    {char}
                </span>
            ))
        }
    </Span>
  )
}

export default AnimatedLetters
```

Comment: I do not get your question though.
Are you not able to see the translated data?

Or what actually is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If I translate the texts normally, it works with no problems. the thing is I want to split the text translated, because if the user change the language, I want the title changing with the good language. So that's why I'm trying to split the translated data, to be dynamic, but everything I triied, send me back an Element, and th split() function can't get an element, just a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found it! I put the solution here in the case of someone else needs it!

In fact there is two ways, don't forget that I needed an array to transmet to my component, so the first was to put directly an array into my translations json files, like:

### common.json

```json
{
    "Title": ["A","b","o","u","t","","u","s"]
}
```

But i did not thought that was very clean.

So the second way was to create a method that tooks the key of the json file, to return it directly, like this :

```js
const getTranslate = (value: string) => {
        return (`${t(value)}`)
}
```

Then I stringify it to can use `.split()` to make an array

```js
const getTranslate = (value: string) => {
        return JSON.stringify(`${t(value)}`).split("")
    }
```

The translate and the array worked nicely, but it returned with double quotes. The last thing was to erase it, with a replace and a little regex, and now : everything works like a charm

All the component looks like it now :

### About.tsx

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import AnimatedLetters from "../AnimatedLetters/AnimatedLetters"
import { Div } from "../Layout/Layout.elements";
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const About = () => {

    const [letterClass, setLetterClass] = useState('text-animate');
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setLetterClass('text-animate-hover')
        }, 3000)
    }, [])

    const getTranslate = (value: string) => {
        return JSON.stringify(`${t(value)}`).replace(/\"/g, "").split("")
    }

  return (
    <Div>
        <div className="container about-page">

            <div className="text-zone">
                <h1>
                    <AnimatedLetters
                        strArray={getTranslate('Title')} // <<--- Called here
                        idx={15}
                        letterClass={letterClass}
                    />
                </h1>

            </div>


        </div>
    </Div>
  )
}

export default About
```